# What is the percentage of the songs, you have listened to today, did you like?

Tags: word-order

> 1 What is the percentage of the songs, you have listened to today, did
> you like?
>
> 2 What is the percentage of the songs, you have listened to today, you
> liked?
>
> 3 What is the percentage of the songs, you have listened to today,
> that you liked?

I think only 3 is grammatical. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Option (3) might be the best, but none of them are great.

(1) is obviously not grammatical, as there are two conflicting questions ("*what is...*" and "*did you...*").

(2) and (3) have unnecessary commas. The phrase "you have listened to today" is not parenthetical so should not be offset the way it is. I suspect whoever wrote this used them to represent pauses in speech to break down what is a very long question so that it is received better.

But the problem with all of them is that they are unclear. Talking about percentages is tricky. A percentage is essentially a fraction where the denominator is always 100. A fraction is meaningless without both the numerator and the denominator; likewise, your audience must understand what the percentage represents. The problem in this regard with (2) is that it could be mistakenly understood that the whole population is just the songs "you liked", which makes it ambiguous what the percentage then represents. Option 3 makes it a little clearer with the additional conjunction but the commas still confuse it.

I would ask the question this way:

> Of the songs you listened to today, what percentage of them did you like?

This makes clear the denominator,or whole population (all the songs you listened to today), and the numerator (the ones you liked).

Comment: Actually, the point was not the percentage thing but the word order. If it was "What is the name of the song you have listened to today that you liked?" would it be correct?

Comment: @user1425 I have given you an alternative word order that I believe is better. This is from my perspective as a native British English speaker and as an information analyst used to expressing data. I appreciate you didn't ask about the percentage, but your question was just "do you agree?", my answer is *no* and I've explained why. You are asking a very different question now so that is off-topic here.

Comment: (1) would be OK if you left out "is the" and the commas.

Comment: @KateBunting "*What is the percentage of songs you have listened to today did you like?*" - nope that is wrong. There's two questions, "*what is*" and "*did you*".

Comment: @Astralbee - You must have misread my comment. I suggested _What percentage of the songs you have listened to today did you like?_

Answer (score 1):

**of those** would help you out.

Which songs did you like of those you listened to today?

Which of those songs you listened to today did you like?

Of those songs you listened to today, which did you like?

Which did you like of those songs you listened to today?

What is the percentage you liked of those songs you listened to today?

What percentage did you like of those songs you listened to today?

What is the percentage of songs you liked of those you listened to today?

And with **the** instead of *those*:

Of the songs you listened to today, what percentage did you like?

Comment: Albeit correct, I find "[those] songs you listened to today" a bit clumsy, would "[those] songs you listened today" be equally grammatical?

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Give a full sentence.

Comment: What songs did you listen / have you listened today?

Comment: We "listen *to* a song", not "listen a song". But your formulation skirts OP's issue, namely, how to speak of a subset of songs one has listened to.

Comment: But you could change "listen to" to "heard": "... of the songs you heard today". But the meaning is not identical.  But there's nothing "clumsy" about "songs you listened to today".  The natural parsing rhythms keep "listened to" together, with a slight pause after "to",  so there's no *staccato* "to to.."   If that's what you were referring to when you said it was "clumsy".

Comment: I didn't write "listen(ed) a song" I know that is incorrect. Instead I added the adverb, "today", if it was "listen to today's news" I would tell learners that "Listen to the *news* (or *music*) today" will always be correct, and sound just fine but, I think, in fast speech native speakers would probably omit the particle "to" immediately in front of words such as "tomorrow" and "today".

Comment: @Mari-LouA But grammatically speaking you *did* write "listen a song", in  question syntactical order, when you wrote "What songs did you listen today?" And you're wrong that native speakers would omit "to".  That would be ungrammatical, not non-standard, and not colloquial.   As I said, the natural parsing rhythms would keep "listened to" and "today" distinct.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: As Tim says, native speakers don't have a problem with repeating "to" in these contexts. But we're not *really* "repeating" anything significant anyway - partly because they're completely different parts of speech, but mainly because they *sound* different (the vowel in the first syllable of ***today, tomorrow*** would invariable be reduced to just a neutral schwa).

Comment: Yes, extremely exaggerated and in slo-mo:   (listen) toooooo  .... ti daaaay

Comment: @FumbleFingers American native speaker,  highly-educated (presumably), he says [“…he continues to coach me on being a better listener, so to that point, **I listened today,** Doctor, and in listening today…”](https://youtu.be/KnzzkRZZIAE?si=DQHDr4FIR22qEP2j&t=2565)

Comment: [One hundred United States senators **listened today to prosecutors** from the House of Representatives](https://youtu.be/uZdphV_x2Ko?si=StDkl66W8pKDP1xU&t=5) and [Well I know you've sat and **you've listened today to kind of** a conversation among family,](https://youtu.be/0G0wjprwS7o?si=Jh7MZbsQlrsW9J5O&t=2959)

Comment: So, it is possible to say "listened today (to)" these examples may not be a perfect match with the OP's but there's no doubt at all that all three excerpts are grammatical.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: In case you didn't realize, that "macroeconomics" speaker is using a relatively recent (primarily American) adverbial construction *[speak] **to that point***, meaning *[what I'm about to say is] **in the context of that point*** (it's not a resequenced version of ***I listened to that point***). You'll often hear a panel discussion speaker say something like *If I may speak **to that point***, meaning *I have something to say which addresses or is in the context of that point*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA   I want you to listen, and I want you to listen closely: we **listen to** songs and sounds.  We do not "listen songs".   You are way off base to think that your examples have any bearing whatsoever here.  It's not that they are an "imperfect match".  They're not relevant.

Comment: **to listen a song,to listen to a song**. Zero hits on "to listen a song". 
 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+listen+a+song%2Cto+listen+to+a+song&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: When we focus our hearing on a specific source of sound, we "listen to" it. When we keep quiet to allow someone else to speak,so that we can consider their opinion, we "listen" (intransitive).

Comment: When, when did I ever say that "listen a song" was acceptable/grammatical? When? Never. I wanted to know if we could omit "to" in **I have listened yesterday/today**, only *now* you're telling me that it is possible when "listen" is used intransitively. And I thank you for that because I had forgotten, "listen to today", which I immediately said was grammatical, just sounded a bit awkward to me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Perhaps I misunderstood your very first comment above, where you seemed to suggest dropping the preposition **to**:    <Albeit correct, I find "[those] songs you listened to today" a bit clumsy, would "[those] songs you listened today" be equally grammatical? >  and then later on you wrote <I think, in fast speech native speakers would probably omit the particle "to" immediately in front of words such as "tomorrow" and "today">